# Combining Modernizr with Youtube API

Tags: javascript, youtube, modernizr, autoplay, mute

based on a fiddle I found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/BFDKS/9/) (solution autoplay+mute embedded Youtube video) I am trying to combine this with Modernizr. Since Mobile devices don't support video autoplay, they act weird when I try to force autoplay via the Youtube API.

So, the idea is to just trigger this script when Modernizr finds our the browser actually supports videoautoplay. Unfortunately, my js skills are very limited.

Here's a fiddle of what I've got so far: http://jsfiddle.net/qh8v4dhh/1/

```
   if (Modernizr.videoautoplay) {
     showOffAwesomeNewFeature();
   } else {
     getTheOldLameExperience();
   }
```

I'd be glad If anyone could help me with this, the first "showOffAwesomeNewFeature()" should be replaced with the code in my fiddle, while the "getTheOldLameExperience()" should simply do nothing at all.

Comment: in what way do they "act weirdly"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Patrick
Altough this somehow just happens sporadically, the video container turns black and the youtube loading animation appears. It seems like the script tries to force-autoplay the video but the mobile device's settings prevent that. As a result of that, the video cannot be started at all anymore.

Therefore, the best solution would be to combine it with the above Modernizr if-else function. Unfortunately, i have almost zero js experience. Maybe you could give me a hint on how to do that?

Simply replacing ´showOffAwesomeNewFeature();´ with the fiddle's JS doesnt work.

Comment: in what way does it not work?

Comment: I modified my fiddle in a way that I thought how Modernizr would work, but this somehow breaks the whole functionality of the youtube code (just nothing happens).
http://jsfiddle.net/qh8v4dhh/2/
I added some comments to the js so you have an idea of what i did there. My guess is that I just messed up pasting these two scripts together, since I don't have any clue about javascript. Also, if I don't want anything to happen in the "else" scenario, do i just leave it all blank?